# Access proprty of existing object instantiated via linq

Tags: c#, .net, binding

I am using .net 4.5 forms and model binding.

I have a selectmethod on a control that returns an instance of my Ex_Application object via linq to a DetailsView.

My DetailsView is:

```
    <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView_displayApp" runat="server"  DataKeyNames="appID" SelectMethod="Ex_Application_GetData">
<ItemTemplate>    
...    
...
...
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

my code behind selectmethod is shown below:

```
public IQueryable<Ex_Application> Ex_Application_GetData([QueryString("appId")]int applicationID)
{
    DatabaseEntities db = new DatabaseEntities();
    var query = (from e in db.Ex_Application
                 where e.appID == applicationID
                 select e);            

    if (query.Count() == 0)
    {
        Label_ErrorMessage.Text = "There was a problem retrieving the application from the database, please contact a site admin";
        Label_ErrorMessage.Visible = true;

        Logger.LoggerError(Utility.GetUsername_string(),
              "No Application found",
              Request.RawUrl.ToString(),
              "UcApplicationDisplay Ex_Application_GetData",
              "No application found for appID " + applicationID
              );
    }

    return query;
}
```

Ex_Application has a property UserID, I would like to pass this integer to another method before returning the object back to the control, but I can't seem to get to the property, I must be missing something simple.

Has anyone got any suggestions please?

I basically want my method to look something like this:

```
        public IQueryable<Ex_Application> Ex_Application_GetData([QueryString("appId")]int applicationID)
    {
        DatabaseEntities db = new DatabaseEntities();
        var query = (from e in db.Ex_Application
                     where e.appID == applicationID
                     select e);            

        if (query.Count() == 0)
        {
            Label_ErrorMessage.Text = "There was a problem retrieving the application from the database, please contact a site admin";
            Label_ErrorMessage.Visible = true;

            Logger.LoggerError(Utility.GetUsername_string(),
                  "No Application found",
                  Request.RawUrl.ToString(),
                  "UcApplicationDisplay Ex_Application_GetData",
                  "No application found for appID " + applicationID
                  );

            return null;
        }

        ***someOtherMethod(query.UserID);***

        return query;
    }
```

I have googled around and can't seem to find the answer, but maybe I am using incorrect search terms...

Comment: As an FYI model-binding is more often then not specific to MVC (binding values from a request into a model).  Binding is the general case term for binding a class to a UI element.

Comment: Hi Erik, thank you for your comment, the tutorial I had previously followed using the technique described related to it as model-binding with forms, apologies for any confusion.. http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/model-binding/retrieving-data

Comment: Yeah, IMHO that article should have used the word data-binding.